# JavaScript - Calling a function in for loop error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following script which is supposed to take parameters from the URL querystring, put them into an array, and then put the values into text fields.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUtms(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    
    var utmArray = ['utm_campaign','utm_medium','utm_source'];
    for (var i = 0; i < utmArray.length; i++) {
      console.log(utmArray[i]);
      document.querySelector("p." + utmArray[i] + " input").value = getUtms(utmArray[i]);
    }
    </script>

    <input type="text" name="utm_campaign">
    <input type="text" name="utm_medium">
    <input type="text" name="utm_source">
```

However I am getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

related to the line

```
document.querySelector("p." + utmArray[i] + " input").value = getUtms(utmArray[i]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're querying for paragraphs `p.` but i can't see any in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the `input` elements. In your code, as @Reyno pointed out you're querying `p` tags which do not have a `value` property. You can also use `getElementsByName` in order to access the values of each input by the specified name at the current index.

You can rewrite your code like so:

```js
function getUtms(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    
    var utmArray = ['utm_campaign','utm_medium','utm_source'];
    for (var i = 0; i < utmArray.length; i++) {
      console.log(utmArray[i]);
      document.getElementsByName(utmArray[i])[0].value = getUtms(utmArray[i]);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="utm_campaign">
<input type="text" name="utm_medium">
<input type="text" name="utm_source">
```

Comment: @matt-croak thank you! I added a new variable: var utmArrayLength = -1;
And in the for loop I changed it to: for (var i = 0; i < utmArrayLength; i++)
The rest of the code remains the same as my original. Sorry I forgot to put in p tags and classes on the text fields.

Comment: @ianhman I'm confused about the introduction of `var utmArrayLength = -1` as that would result in no looping (the indexes will never be less than -1).

Answer (score 0):

The selector you need is not
`"p." + utmArray[i] + " input"`
but rather
`"input[name="+utmArray[i]+"]"`

i.e. get the input tag with the name attribute equal to utmArray[i]

So in full...

```
document.querySelector("input[name="+utmArray[i]+"]").value = getUtms(utmArray[i]);
```